# Jquery Ajax - Alert firing twice

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, json

The code below is triggered on a click of a button and having followed the request through, it is only being triggered once. Also, having stepped through, the code is only triggered once, however, the alerts show twice. Any suggestions for why?

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppDirectory"]/OperatorApplication/PafSearch/' + pafPostcode.val(),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (response) {
                    addressList.empty();
                    addressSelection.hide();

                    if (response == null) {

                        alert("No addresses found for the postcode provided.\n\nPlease enter your address manually");

                    }                        
        //other processes removed...
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you sure the request is send only once?

Comment: You can check how many times the request is sent using browsers inspection tools (firebug etc.). Probably ajax request is being sent twice from another portion of code. You can put an alert before the $.ajax to check if it is called twice.

Answer (score 1):

How did you bind the click event to the button? Or did you bind the same event multiple times?

Is it like this:

```
$("#targetButton").on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppDirectory"]/OperatorApplication/PafSearch/' + pafPostcode.val(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
            addressList.empty();
            addressSelection.hide();
            if (response == null) {
                alert("No addresses found for the postcode provided.\n\nPlease enter your address manually");
            }
            //other processes removed...
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```